# Get Site Content Type ID by Content Type Name using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, rest, content-type, library

I am having some of the **Site Content Types** available in my SharePoint 2013 site. Now I want to assign this **Site Content Types** to my **Document Library** using REST API.

I have tried [code from here](https://rmanimaran.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-associate-an-existing-content-type-to-a-sharepoint-list/) and it worked perfectly. But the only problem is it required Content Type ID to associate and I am just having **Site Content Types** name.

So I just want to know is there any REST end point available through which I can associate my **Site Content Type** to my library using **Name** instead of **ID**?

I am bound to use REST API only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get content type id from its name. Just you have to use `$filter`.

```
"/_api/web/AvailableContentTypes?$select=Name,Id,StringId&$filter=Name eq 'Your CT Name'"
```

Just make a GET request to the above end-point.

**PS:** `Id` is a `object`. So better you can consider to `$select` `StringId` in your query.

Comment: :-) Got it worked. My knowledge is limited in REST API...

Comment: You have asked a nice question! I did not know before about this end-point. After seeing your questing, I have just explored it using my REST client. You can also use REST client to explore REST API.

Comment: Hi @AakashMorya, I have made a REST Client. You can check if it can help you to explore REST API. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-rest-client/ojnaikgchcnginnmkmkonmdglhjikokd

Comment: Will definitely check :-)