# Retrieve content type id from content type name using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-addin, csom, content-type

I have site **content type** available in my SP 2013 site, I need Content Type ID by content type name using CSOM.

I found the way by using rest api from here [Get Site Content Type ID by Content Type Name using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/188097/get-site-content-type-id-by-content-type-name-using-rest-api)

But i am restricted to use CSOM.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using C# CSOM you can try something like this [ContentTypeCollection Extension](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115499/get-a-content-type-by-name-title-using-csom)

```
// taken from link above!!!
public static class ContentTypeExtensions
{
    public static ContentType GetByName(this ContentTypeCollection cts, string name)
    {
        var ctx = cts.Context;
        ctx.Load(cts);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        return Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(cts, ct => ct.Name == name);
    }
}
```

Once you return the content type by name using the extension method, you should be able to pull the ID off of the variable.

```
var siteCT = ctx.Site.RootWeb.ContentTypes.GetByName("<Name>");

var CTID = siteCT.Id;
```